# How to view a pdf file and an image file remotely from terminal?

Tags: ssh, osx

I am using a macbook and i have an another computer with linux installed in it. 
I tried to view an image file upon ssh login by using 
**eog ./1.jpg**      and    **gpicview ./1.jpg**  but nothing worked and i got these errors while using them[image]

I tried **evince** to view pdf file but it is not working.

Someone please help me out of this

Answer (score 1):

Install [XQuartz](https://www.xquartz.org/) and SSH with X11 forwarding enabled so that the `DISPLAY` environment variable is set after connecting to the other system.

```
% ssh -XY somelinuxbox 
...
-bash-4.1$ echo $DISPLAY 
localhost:10.0
-bash-4.1$
```